# What does "ter" mean?

Tags: vocabulary, dialect

I couldn't find the meaning of "ter" in any dictionaries. Here's the context:

> "What about that tea then, eh?" He said, rubbing his hands together.
> "I'd not say no **ter** summat stronger if yeh've got it, mind."

What does "**ter**" mean? Thanks!

Comment: What is the source of the quote?

Comment: @Void from a novel.

Comment: @Void - Harry Potter and the Philosopher's Stone.

Comment: Please always post the source.

Comment: The only thing I'd add to the existing answers is that "ter" should be read non-rhotically.

Comment: Hagrid's speech in the HP books is such a constant source of questions here that we should probably have a tag for it!

Comment: @stangdon when I Googled for the text to find the source there were plenty of questions on language Q & A sites for exactly that text. DV for lack of research!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> ter summat stronger if yeh've got it

is used to show heavy accent or a dialect by writing words as they are pronounced (see [Phonemic orthography](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phonemic_orthography)).

Here ***ter*** would be the phonemic orthography of ***to***:

> I wouldn't say no ***to*** ***something*** stronger if ***you***'ve got it, mind.

(I have written in bold the words that were replaced to imitate accent.)

This [site](https://topmeaning.com/english/ter) indicates that this is how ***to*** is spelled in ***Eye dialect***. [WordSenseDict](https://www.wordsense.eu/ter/) agrees.

Comment: It is not an attempt. It is a way of showing dialect.

Comment: "Summat" doesn't mean "somewhat".  In Yorkshire and Derbyshire dialects, "summat" = "something".

Comment: @rjpond: It can mean "somewhat" too according to this [source](https://www.wordsense.eu/summat/). But you are right, I should include all variants. Will edit.

Comment: Modern people that say summat like 'summat' in their speech, meaning 'something', are very unlikely to use 'somewhat' either in a standard or dialectical way. That source was from _Adam Bede_ (George Eliot, 1859).

Comment: Summat goes right down from Yorkshire/Lancashire via the Midlands to the West Country (they say it in Bristol).

Comment: @MichaelHarvey I understand. 'summat' meaning 'somewhat' is outdated.

Answer (score 2):

The book is using Hagrid's voice to show he comes from a rougher, less high class background.
In plain English, he says:
"I'd not say no to something stronger if you've got it, mind."
The use of "I'd not say no" instead of "I wouldn't say no" adds to the effect.

Comment: Right, to becomes ter in his speech.